# A4 thesis-like CSS: taking citations from the main column and placing them into the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, typography

I'm attempting to achieve the following layout based on [this PhD thesis](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~turon/turon-thesis.pdf):

[image]

But is there a pure CSS way to take HTML citations out of one column and placing them in line in the other column?

```css
.Grid {
  display: flex;
}

.Grid-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Grid-cell:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
}

.Grid-cell:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

q {
  /* Insert here */
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Grid-cell">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi <q cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q>. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis
      autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-cell"><!-- Insert here --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, what would appear in the rightmost column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be overthinking this one a bit.  You don't need to set it up as a flex layout and you don't need to copy elements from one location to another.  All you really need is to break a `q` element out of flow and display it in a predefined margin.  We can do this using only `padding-right` and `position: absolute`.

Example here:

```css
.Grid {
  padding-right: 30%;
}

.Grid-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

q[cite] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

q[cite]:before {
  content: attr(data-index);
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Grid-cell">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi<sup>1</sup> <q data-index="1. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q>. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis
      autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't define a `top` or `bottom` property on absolutely positioned elements, they determine where they land based on where they'd appear in document flow.  Therefore, by only setting `position: absolute` and `left: 75%` we've broken your citation out, kept it in-line with its source, and using the `data-index` property in conjunction with a `content: attr(data-index);` even given you the ability to number your citations to match their source inline.

Comment: Hi, good riddance with flexbox! However there's one problem - what to do when there are multiple citations close to each other? https://jsfiddle.net/m1zhvmss/

Comment: In that case, you'd need to provide 1 `q` element and then put all your citations in there, like so: `<q cite><q cite="src">Blah</q><q cite="src2">Bleh</q></q>` and then add a CSS rule like `q[cite] > q { position: static; display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px; }`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not using flexbox.

But using an internal span and positioning this can be achieved.

*Incidentally, I have used a `cite` tag in place of the `q` tag as `q` renders automatic quotes. It may be possible to remove them using CSS but I haven't looked into that.*

```css
.Grid {
  display: flex;
}

.Grid-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Grid-cell:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  position: relative;
  
}

.Grid-cell:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

sup {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: red;
  font-size:.6em;
}

cite span {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  margin-right: -8em;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Grid-cell">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi<sup>1</sup><cite cite="http://www.mashable.com/"><span>1. My Citation</span></cite>. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis
      autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid-cell"><!-- Insert here --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, as with Josh's answer, I'm struggling when there are multiple citations close to each other: https://jsfiddle.net/dtL2x61L/ - can you think of anything?

Comment: There's only so much you can do with HTML & CSS alone. Sometimes it needs help from javascript.